# How to filter out Flux<Example> that don't contain some value from Flux<String>

Tags: project-reactor

So let's say I have a `Flux<String> firstLetters` containing `"A", "B", "C", "D"` and `Flux<String> lastLetters` containing `"X", "Y", "Z"`

And I have a Flux containing many:

```
data class Example(val name: String)
```

And from the whole `Flux<Example>` I want to split the elements to two variables: one `Flux<Example>` containing all that `name IN ("A", "B", "C", "D")` and second `Flux<Example>` that has name `IN ("X", "Y", "Z")` and save those two Fluxes two variables.

Is it possible to do so in one flow without doing same logic first for `firstLetters` and then for `lastLetters`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to do so in one flow without doing same logic first for firstLetters and then for lastLetters

As the problem stands I don't believe so, as you'll have to process each element multiple times (one per each value on the list to see if it contains the value you need.) You can call `cache()` on the `Flux` though to ensure that the values are only retrieved once, or convert to another data structure entirely.

Given that you have to re-evaluate anyway, and assuming you still want to stick with raw `Flux` objects, `filterWhen()` and `any()` can be used quite nicely here:

```
Flux<Example> firstNames = names.filterWhen(e -> firstLetters.any(e.name::contains));
Flux<Example> lastNames = names.filterWhen(e -> lastLetters.any(e.name::contains));
```

You can of course pull the `Predicate` out into a separate method if you're concerned about code duplication there.

Answer (score 0):

If `Flux<String> firstLetters/lastLetters` can be replaced with `Set<String> firstLetters/lastLetters` then you can easily leverage `Flux::groupBy` method on `Flux<Example>` to split it into different groups.

```
enum Group {
  FIRST, LAST, UNDEFINED
}

Group toGroup(Example example) {
  if (firstLetters.contains(example.name)) return FIRST;
  else if (lastLetters.contain(example.name)) return LAST;
  else return UNDEFINED;
}

Flux<GroupedFlux<Group, Example>> group(Flux<Example> examples) {
  return examples.groupBy(example -> toGroup(example));
}
```

You can then get the group by calling `GroupedFlux<K, V>::key`.